How to place six different-sized graphs in a figure in a two-column document?

How can I place the figures as shown in two-column paper?
ratio:
big square: 0.4 X 0.4
small square: 0.3 X 0.3
small rectangle: 0.2 X 0.4
Thank you very much

Sorry, I did not mention the ratio.
big square: 0.40.4
small square: 0.30.3
small rectangle: 0.2*0.4

Welcome to TeX.SE, also please post your MWE too

please also re-tag. overleaf is just your editor.

Should the width of the complete figure be equal to 1\textwidth, or maybe a fraction of \textwidth? Please advise.

And, please indicate (a) which document class you employ and (b) whether the full graph should be displayed in landscape mode.

@CarLaTeX - I wouldn't say it's an exact duplicate, as there's a new "twist", viz., the need to use a figure* environment.

@Mico Not a great difference :D

The following answer borrows freely from my answer to the recent query Subfigure arrangement with relatively complex combination of shapes and sizes. In particular, since the dimensional information you've provided is more about relative than about absolute sizes, it employs a \resizebox directive to set the overall width of the group of six rectangles to a fraction of \textwidth. The two minipage environments, in contrast, employ absolute dimensions.
You haven't indicated how wide the full group of graphs should be, so I'll assume that it's 1\textwidth. You've indicated that you're working in a two-column setup; I hence recommend using a figure* environment, which spans both columns. The solution uses the IEEEtran document class as it employs a two-column setup; feel free to employ a different document class. Note that figure* objects by default are placed at the top of a page.

\documentclass{IEEEtran} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\resizebox' and '\includegraphics' macros
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5] % filler text

\begin{figure*} % will be placed at top of next page

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{4cm} % first minipage
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm]{example-image} 

\vspace{1.5mm} % feel free to choose a different value

\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{example-image}           
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1.5mm}%
\begin{minipage}{6.15cm} % second minipage; 6.15=3+0.15+3 
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}% 
\hspace{1.5mm}%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}

\vspace{1.5mm}

\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}% 
\hspace{1.5mm}%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
\end{minipage}}

\caption{Hello World} % choose a suitable caption
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[6-16] % more filler text

\end{document}

